# Exporting database using cmdwing

Tags: mysql, database, cmd, export

i was trying to export my database using cmd but i encountered the following error...

C:>cd program files

C:\Program Files>cd MySQl

C:\Program Files\MySQL>cd MySQL Server 5.1

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1>cd bin

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin>mysqldump -u root -p root try > dump
_file.sql
Access is denied.

how can get past this.

Also i tried the following.....

How can i export my database using mysql command line client.tried the following things but didn't work.

mysql> mysqldump -u root -p hms > qaz.sql;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
dump -u root -p hms > qaz.sql' at line 1

plz help me either of these. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this at the end of your command to store the file on your desktop.
You can use the %temp% folder too.

In modern Windows you can't write to program files folders.

```
>"%userprofile%\desktop\dump _file.sql"
```